# SOLR Delete collection - orphaned replica - how to delete?

Tags: solr

We created a collection to test CDCR but had to delete it after testing.
After we deleted collection there is a orphan replica showing up in the core selector dropdown of admin UI which is not linked to any collection. We are trying to delete that replica. Usual replica delete API calls fail as the collection is no longer there on solr.

Any pointers towards - how to delete orphaned replica?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CoreAdmin UNLOAD core API to unload a shard , you can find the core node number from solr.home directory and core.properties file if it is not visible in clusterstate.json

From Solr Cwiki

The UNLOAD action removes a core from Solr. Active requests will continue to be processed, but no new requests will be sent to the named core. If a core is registered under more than one name, only the given name is removed.

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=core0

Comment: Tried this but was throwing exception for non existent core. Restarting the solr service cleared the orphaned replicas. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: I had the same problem , you need the same server as the shard is present in ,did you try that ? 
There is another way to remove a core you can navigate to solr.home folder and remove the core node of that folder which usually named as test_shard1_replica1.